# Inserting records into table1 depending on row value in table2

Tags: postgresql

For each row in table exam 'where exam.examRegulation isnull', I want to insert one corresponding row in table examRegulation and copy columnvalues from exam to examregulation. Apparently the following query ist too naive and must be approved:

```
insert into examRegulation (graduation, course, examnumber, examversion) 
values (exam.graduation, exam.course, exam.examnumber, exam.examversion)
where ?? (select graduation, course, examnumber, examversion
from exam
where exam.examRegulation isnull)
```

Is there a way to do this in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

You may rephrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO examRegulation (graduation, course, examnumber, examversion)
SELECT graduation, course, examnumber, examversion
FROM exam
WHERE examRegulation IS NULL;
```

The `VALUES` clause, as the name implies, can only be used with literal values.  If you need to populate an insert using query logic, then you need to use a `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to extend the query so that the table exam is ubdated simultaneously with the new generated examRegulation numbers from table examRegulation, so in the end the query select * from exam where examRegulation IS NULL returns empty result?

Comment: I don't know of an automatic way to do this.  Typically, a business problem would be that the primary table already exists, and you would be inserting a child record after that.